# Corruption of moral ideas

Tags: ethics

I've been thinking about American Dream lately and this question struck me: are we the ones to corrupt moral ideas, or are the ideas corrupted by themselves? American Dream's an absolutely moral ideology, but in practice the followers of the Dream incline to immoral acts. This can be applied to any moral ideology.

Comment: As written the question is not particularly clear. Could you work on revising it and making sure it's a good fit for this stack exchange?

Comment: Feel free to edit your question and then tag me @virmaior so I can reopen it if revised to something clearer and more clearly a fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideas are not actors. Actors in ethics are always persons.

Hence moral ideas cannot corrupt themselves.

But persons can misinterpret or abandon ideas. Or as you axpressed it "we [are] the ones to corrupt moral ideas."

**Added** after your comments:
As I understand from your comments, your question is:

> Why is it that "The followers of [american] dream will even commit crimes and sins in order to get money. This contradicts the main principle of the dream."

There are several possible explanations:

1. Those who commit those crimes are not the same as those who subscribed to the dream.
2. Those who subsribed to the dream changed their opinion.
3. Ideas and dreams are not strong enough to suppress actions which offend these dreams. Actions can be induced by more powerful drives and desires.

Comment: Why is this so?

Comment: Please indicate to which part of my answer you question refers, thank you.

Comment: Why do we corrupt the ideas? If you know any theory relative to it do not hesitate linking it here.

Comment: Before explaining "Why?" it would be helpful to determine what it is, which has to be explained. Hence could you please give some examples how "the followers of the Dream incline to immoral acts". What are you thinking about?

Comment: The followers of dream will even commit crimes and sins in order to get money. This contradicts the main principle of the dream.

Comment: Surely you could add to this list that it is simply part of the human condition - we hold ideals and values that we ourselves repeatedly fail to live up to?

Comment: @CCarter Indeed, I first considered to add a pointer to the general human condition to my list. But eventually I considered this point being self-evident :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think they *betray* their dream (and themselves) rather than corrupting the dream. As Jo pointed out, the ideal remains what it is, it is the persons that are corrupted (e.g. by greed), not the ideal.

What you are pointing at is an equivocation: that the term "americal dream" happens to be used for the behaviour of persons claiming to follow it, but are corrupted. But "american *dream*" inherentially *remains* an ideal, despite what the term is *also* used for. That's a standard problem of a living language.

=> In expressing that "the american dream corrupts itself" you are using the term in another way than "the american dream" is normally used, namely as an ideal. And ideals are normative *per se*.